# Getting data from customer attribute checkbox type in Magento 1 issue

Tags: magento-1, register, checkbox

I created a customer attribute with `Text field` as an `Input Type` . I selected the `Show on Frontend` on `Yes` . I went to the register phtml file and I added:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_attribute_code" checked title="Custom Text" id="my_attribute_code" >
```

If I checked my checkbox in the post request I got the value `on` If I do not check it , it is an empty array. The fact is that in `customer_entity_varchar` table for my attribute the `value` column is always empty . Why ? 
If i checked my checkbox I would expect to have the `on` value in the table.

Comment: Have you done it yet?

Comment: Did you solved ?of yes then please let us know